# Prove that $\sup\left (\frac{1}{A}\right )=\frac{1}{\inf A}.$

Tags: solution-verification, supremum-and-infimum

Let $\varnothing\neq A\subseteq \mathbb R^+$, such that $\inf A>0$, then $$\sup\left (\dfrac{1}{A}\right )=\dfrac{1}{\inf A}.$$

**My Try:** Notice that $\inf A\leq a$ for all $a\in A$. Then, $1/a\leq 1/\inf A$, so $\sup(1/A)\leq 1/\inf A$.

On the other hand, we have $p\leq \sup(1/A)$ for all $p\in \dfrac{1}{A}$. Then, $\dfrac{1}{\sup(1/A)}\leq 1/p$, where $1/p\in A$. So $\dfrac{1}{\sup(1/A)}\leq \inf A$. Then, $\dfrac{1}{\inf A}\leq \sup(1/A)$.

That way we have to $\sup(1/A)\leq \dfrac{1}{\inf A}$ and $\dfrac{1}{\inf A}\leq \sup(1/A)$ Consequently, $\sup(1/A)=\dfrac{1}{\inf A}$. My proof is correct?

Comment: I think it is correct +1:)

Comment: Oh thanks. I appreciate it. :)))

Comment: I have changed the formatting of the title so as to [make it take up less vertical space](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9686/290189) -- this is a policy to ensure that the scarce space on the main page is distributed evenly over the questions.  See [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9730/290189) for more information. Please take this into consideration for future questions. Thanks in advance.